# How to change the font & color when using Html.TextAreaFor?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm using following code to display some text and it won't change the font color, anyone know why?

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Component.ApplicationDescription, new { cols = "40%", Style = new Style { ForeColor = Color.Red } })%>
```

Comment: use CSS class .. it is better

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Component.ApplicationDescription, 
    new { cols = "40%", style = "color:red;" })%>
```

or apply a css style:

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Component.ApplicationDescription, 
    new { cols = "40%", @class = "foo" })%>
```

which could look like this:

```
.foo {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: or using `{}` in `Style = new Style { ForeColor = Color.Red } `??!

Comment: @jjj, using `Style = new Style { ForeColor = Color.Red }` will generate the following HTML: `Style="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style"` which is far from what browsers consider as valid HTML.

Comment: now im curious - is there a way to use strongly typed styles in this manner? would be kinda nice. thanks